# Does SSL provide point-to-point security?

Tags: security, ssl

According to the following quote, SSL provides point-to-point security:

> Transport security is used to provide
>   point-to-point security between the
>   two endpoints  (service and client).
>   If there are intermediary systems
>   between the client and the server,
>   each intermediate point must forward
>   the message over a new SSL connection.

a) What is meant by SSL providing point-to-point security?

b) Is SSL communication still possible between client and server, if intermediary system ( located between the client and the server ) forwards the message over a non-SSL connection?

c) Assuming it is possible ... I don't see why intermediary system  forwarding messages over a non-SSL connection would provide less security, since messages are already encypted by original sender ( which is either client or server ) and thus can't be decrypted by an intermediary systems?

thank you

EDIT:

> One limitation of transport security
>   is that it relies on every “step” and
>   participant in the network path having
>   consistently conﬁgured security. In
>   other words, if a message must travel
>   through an intermediary before
>   reaching its destination, there is no
>   way to ensure that transport security
>   has been enabled for the step after
>   the intermediary (unless that interme-
>   diary is fully controlled by the
>   original service provider). If that
>   security is not faithfully reproduced,
>   the data may be compromised
>   downstream. In addition, the
>   intermediary itself must be trusted
>   not to alter the message before
>   continuing transfer. These
>   considerations are especially
>   important for services available via
>   Internet-based routes, and typically
>   less important for systems exposed and
>   consumed within a corporate intranet.
>
> Message security focuses on ensuring
>   the integrity and privacy of individ-
>   ual messages, without regard for the
>   network. Through mechanisms such as
>   encryption and signing via public and
>   private keys, the message will be
>   protected even if sent over an
>   unprotected transport (such as plain
>   HTTP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the context of that quote is different than you seem to be assuming; by 'intermediate system', I think that quote means a system that must access the message in the middle (intentionally or not)... not just a router, but something actually decrypting, viewing and/or modifying the message.

Therefore, because SSL is 'point to point', the above is actually not possible without another, separate connection being made.

Comment: And wouldn't that be impossible if one were using host certificates?

Comment: When I speak of 'separate connection', I mean a totally separate connection - *not* an intermediate system at all. That's the meaning of 'point to point' in this context: You can't have other systems involved but the client and server; to get anything else involved, it needs to be a separate connection entirely. A connects to B, and B connects to C. Two totally different connections. C is *not* connecting to A at all.

Comment: Are you saying that text talks about situation where we have three systems A, B and C, with B connecting A and C (thus B is in the middle), and we want all the traffic between A and C to be encypted using SSL. And if it happens that specific messages going from A to C need to make a stop at B (get decrypted there for processing and then again encrypted and sent forward to C), then we essentially need to have three separate SSL connections --> between A and B and between B and C and between A and C(for messages that don't need to get decrypted at B)?

Comment: From seeing just that quote itself, that text is basically just saying that to have more than two systems involved, you need more connections - there's no way to incorporate more than two systems in a single SSL connection (barring vulnerabilities in the implementation). If A needs to communicate with both B and C at once, it must make separate connections to each. If B needs to see what A is sending to C, then B needs to make separate connections to A and C (and both A and C need to connect to B).

Comment: And yes, the three-way communication you speak of requires three separate connections... but that's not a requirement of SSL - any three-way, direct communication requires three connections.

Comment: Hope this will make sense: Ok, so what does make transport-level security less secure than message level security? As you've noted, B can't decrypt messages from SSL connection between A and B. So other option would be that text is talking about situation where SSL connection is from A to B, where B decrypts the message and then encrypts it back, establishes a new SSL connection between B and C and then forwards message to C - in this situation the security issue would be if  B can't open a new SSL connection and thus must send message unencrypted.

Comment: In that case message level security would be safer, since with message level security B can always encrypt message back, even if it can't open a new SSL connection to C. That would make sense, if text in my EDIT ( could you see my edit :) ) wouldn't talk about intermediary not being under the control of original sender? And why the frack would you send willingly data for processing to system you don't trust, before that system sends it forward to final recipient?!

Comment: 20 pages further into the book author of the quote I've posted in my edit explained what he actually meant by it, and it is as you've said it. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The messages are encrypted at the endpoints. The only way to have a non-SSL connection in the middle would be to emulate both endpoints somewhere in the middle, which would be extraordinarily difficult barring flaws in the SSL implementations on either of the endpoints.