# Example of Intermediate System for Soap Processing

Tags: wcf, soap

When you read about WCF Message Security and compare it to Transport security, one of the drawbacks that they always mention is that transport security is point-to-point and can't secure a message routed through intermediaries.

What is an example of these intermediaries. When would you use one?

All my experience with services is with point-to-point communication so I'm trying to build a context for when you might encounter a SOAP intermediary or router or proxy.

There are other questions on SO that beat around what I'm getting at but don't directly answer my question. For example, in this question:

[Does SSL provide point-to-point security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280145/does-ssl-provide-point-to-point-security)

the answer says:

> intermediate system', I think that quote means a system that must
>   access the message in the middle (intentionally or not)... not just a
>   router, but something actually decrypting, viewing and/or modifying
>   the message.

My question is: What would be an example of a system that need to view/decrypt/modify the message and why would it need to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a partial answer in this document from MS:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647097.aspx

Part of it says:

Message layer security that uses X.509 certificates is flexible enough to provide point-to-point or end-to-end security. This allows messages to be persisted in a secure state for short periods for queue-based processing or for longer periods in an archived state.

So an example would be if a message were queued or stored off to disk. It would stay encrypted through the time it was processed and deleted from disk, presumably.

Edit: Here is a really good article on building a WCF Service Router that explains some of the reasons you might want to use one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500646.aspx

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731081.aspx